# Subversion - Reintegrating trunk to my branch deletes branch files

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I've made branch B from trunk T.

I've changed some files, added some files to B, committed.

I've changed some files in trunk T, committed.

When I try to merge the changes on T into B, the new files in B are deleted. Why does this happen?

EDIT: here is how I merged
[image]

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Please comment if you'd like me to change the question somehow...

Comment: Can you please detail the actions you performed (with TortoiseSVN) for the merge ?

Comment: Hi Laurent, I've edited what I've done. I've also switched to merging via IntelliJ, which seems to not have the same behavior. Cheers

Comment: You should use "Merge a range of revisions" and then select to merge from branch to trunk (and not the opposite)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't `merge two different trees`. What you're essentially doing when running this command is merging the commits from both directories at the same time; therefore causing issues.

As Laurent H. said in the comments, use `Merge a range of revisions` and the URL to merge from would be the trunk's URL.

One thing to note as you do `svn merge` on your branch, is that if you check the radio button that says "specific range", if you leave this box blank, the merge will continue from the latest revision specified in the svn:mergeinfo property that is automatically created when you run an `svn merge`. To put it simply, as you do more merges from the trunk, it will continue from where it left off if you click "specific range" and leave it blank.